# How to recognize which form is calling the saveAction?

Tags: php, module, adminhtml, adminform

I currently have two forms, each on a different page, and each with a different model (Each model links to its own table in the database), in the same adminhtml module. My structure is as follows:

[image]

The AppapiController.php has the saveAction, which is being called from these two forms.

My question is two fold:

1) Is this the right way of doing things? Or am I supposed make a different module or controller for each form?

2) If this is the right way of doing things, how can I know which form is calling the saveAction, so that I known which model to save into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this:

You can create a separate controller where you have a saveAction and call the different controllers on the forms.

Or you can create a second action (for example saveAboutAction) in the controller and point one form to the new action and the other to the normal saveAction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a preference out of the two?

Comment: Forgot to mentoin that, I would prefer the first solution as this is also done in the core this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra hidden field in each form with a different value. then you can read that value sent through POST and know which form is calling it.